# React - Multiple API Requests in Loop

Tags: reactjs, async-await, request, try-catch

I have multiple GET API requests i want to do in a Loop.
What is the best way to do this using await in a try/catch.

I have something like this currently:

```
requestItems.forEach(url => {
        
        try {
          data = await apiService.get(url);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run it in parallel you can do something like this:

```
const requestAll = async () => {  
  return await Promise.all(requestItems.map(async url => {
    try {
      return await apiService.get(url);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }));
}
```